# Managing script execution using GUI "buttons" from Tkinter module

Tags: python, tkinter

there is following script:

```
import sys, Tkinter

def myScript():
    ...

    ...


def runScript():
    while 1:
        myScript()
```

i want to manage it using GUI "button" from Tkinter module

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = Frame ()
    win.pack ()
    Label(win, text='Choose following action', font=("Helvetica", 16), width=70, height=20).pack(side=TOP)
    Button(win, text='Start script', width=20, height=3, command=runScript).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(win, text='Stop script', width=20, height=3, command=sys.exit).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(win, text='Quit', width=15, height=2, command=win.quit).pack(side=RIGHT)
    mainloop()
```

when i type "Start script" button my script successfully started and working (infinite loop), but then i want to stop execution using "Stop script" button i can not do this, since main window with buttons is unavailable ("not responding")

What must i change in order to use both buttons correctly?

Comment: The `threading` module may be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the execution of the script is considered blocked, so while it continually runs the control is never returned back to the GUI to be able to continue with any external commands to stop it. To adjust this you will need to use threading. The best way to do this would to subclass your script method with `threading.Thread` and overloading the `.run()` method with your script execution. Doing so would look like this:

```
import threading

class MyScript(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyScript, self).__init__()
        self.__stop = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self.__stop.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self.__stop.isSet()

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped():
            # Put your script execution here
            print "running"
```

From there you can setup a global variable or class variable to keep track of if you currently have a thread running (you may want to do this differently if you want a user to run multiple instances of the script) and methods to start and stop it. I'd recommend a class variable with your application being a class itself but that's up to you.

```
script_thread = None

def startScript():
    global script_thread
    # If we don't already have a running thread, start a new one
    if not script_thread:
        script_thread = MyScript()
        script_thread.start()

def stopScript():
    global script_thread
    # If we have one running, stop it
    if script_thread:
        script_thread.stop()
        script_thread = None
```

From there you can bind those methods to your buttons. I'm not sure how you have your application structure setup (it seems to me you imported everything from Tkinter or sub-classed the Tkinter.Tk() instance). However in order to do what you propose you will need to use threading to prevent a blocking situation.

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox as tkmsg

win = None

def myScript():
    pass

def runScript():
    global win
    while 1:
        win.update()
        pass

def btnStop_Click():
    tkmsg.showinfo("Stopped", "Stopped")
    sys.exit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global win
    win = Frame ()
    win.pack ()
    Label(win, text='Choose following action', font=("Helvetica", 16), width=70, height=20).pack(side=TOP)
    Button(win, text='Start script', width=20, height=3, command=runScript).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(win, text='Stop script', width=20, height=3, command=btnStop_Click).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(win, text='Quit', width=15, height=2, command=win.quit).pack(side=RIGHT)
    mainloop()
```

Comment: This answer is an anti-pattern. You already have an infinite loop running, there's no need to create your own infinite loop that calls `update`.

Comment: What is your solution ?? @Bryan